# JSON.eval undefined in a certain PC

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, jscript

This will probably sound stupid, but I can't figure out what's happening and it's starting to be kind of a big problem.

I'm working on a .Net web application that uses, among other JS libraries, JSON (not json2). In a certain proxy, the function JSON.eval() is used. Oddly, this method appears to be undefined in the computer of a member of our testing team. On my computer (running against the same servers as her) I have the following JSON object:

```
JSON 
{
    copyright : "(c)2005 JSON.org",
    license : ...
    stringify : ...
    eval : ...
    parse : ...
}
```

While in the problematic PC (both are Win7, with IE9) evaluating JSON from the debugger console only gives:

```
JSON 
{
stringify : ...
    parse : ...
}
```

It seems as if I were missing something obvious...

Comment: Is the browser running in IE7/IE8 mode instead of IE9?

Comment: compatibility mode might be causing this problem, or some other security setting, that shields of the JScript/JavaScript engine... Just for this once I'm finding myself appreciating the choice made by IE to _not_ support `eval` in any shape or form :)

Comment: @epascarello No, both are executing in IE9 mode, I suspected that also.

Comment: @epascarello Cache was cleared. CCleaner was run. Several times each. It doesn't happen with Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere, you seem to be including an old version of the third-party JSON object implementation from http://www.json.org/js.html. `JSON.eval()` is not a standard method, and it's not in Crockford's JSON anymore, either. The second one seems to be the browser native implementation; `.stringify()` and `.parse()` are, indeed, the only guaranteed methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Edit: In other words, the best solution is to change your code to use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: The parse method is probably the best solution. But I'd love to know what the f*** is going on. The application is served via IIS, and different PCs with similar environment appear to be receiving different JSON files. Doesn't make any sense. I know it sounds like I'm just making something stupid and asking without properly troubleshooting it, but I don't think that's the case.